# C# - Calling Web Service Concurrently/Async with Throttling

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

How can I call a web service x number of times concurrently using C#?

I have a table of customers (around 1 million) and I need to call a web service with batches of 5,000 customers to return some info and write to a file.

I've tried using async/await and TPL Dataflow library but the code is so much slower than using plain old synchronous methods. Below is a summary of what I'm trying to achieve. The code will be run from a console app (Main method) that can't be marked async.

```
public void GenerateCustomerFile(){

     var outputFileName = "MyCustomerFile.txt";
     var customers = CustomerRepo.GetCustomers();
     var customerBatch = new List<Customer>();     

     foreach(var customer in customers){

        customerBatch.Add(customer);

        if(customerBatch.Count >= 20000){
            // Call web service concurrently (4 threads with 5000 customers each)
           // Write results to file
           customerBatch.Clear();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a loop for this? You can just split this up and send batches of 5K

```
var customerBatch = CustomerRepo.GetCustomers();
const int batchSize = 5000;
var sendingTasks = Enumerable.Range(0,(customerBatch.Length/batchSize)).Select(async a=>{
   var section = customerBatch.Skip(a*batchSize).Take((a+1)*batchSize);
   await "https://lolcow.com/api/entity".PostJsonAsync(section);
});
await Task.WhenAll(sendingTasks);
```

I am using Flurl for the http request, wasn't sure what you were using for this..but this should do what you are doing...if it is slower than just doing all of them then you may need to make the batches larger

For the question about main methods and async, usually what I do is just make a main async and call that with wait in my main method

```
public static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    //do stuff here
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync(args).Wait();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try this. What about calling this async code from the main method -- how are you doing that without causing deadlocks?

Comment: And how are you actually limiting the number of tasks in this case? If I have 1 million records, isn't this going to start up to 200 concurrent tasks?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, it should optimize the way tasks are being handled. If this is in your main method would suggest making an async method task and waiting on it

Comment: I need to guarantee that only x number of calls are being made. How can I achieve this?